# g++ unable to find standard lib functions

Tags: g++

I'm  trying to compile g++ source code.  The code is from a research group in Taiwan.
Presumably the code compiles for them just fine.  However, when I compile, g++ is unable to find standard lib methods such as atoi and abort. I get the following error when I try to compile:

```
grdb/parser.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Parser07::parse(Builder*)’:
grdb/parser.cpp:40: error: ‘abort’ was not declared in this scope
grdb/parser.cpp: In member function ‘void Parser07::parseRoutingRegion()’:
grdb/parser.cpp:55: error: ‘atoi’ was not declared in this scope
```

I'm  using g++ 4.4.7.  Programs I write are able to compile using those functions.
I was just wondering if I was forgetting something stupid.
Again, this code is able to work for the group I got it from.

Thanks

Comment: is this code including `#include <stdlib.h>` somewhere?

Comment: Do a `man atoi` to see what header files are needed -- they probably just forgot to include them, while they were accidentally included through a different file on their system (which can happen if they have a different distro or release of linux)

Comment: If the code is openly available, you can tell us how to download it. In this way more, people can try and find out the problem.